# In terminal type "edit package.json", then launch package.json with Sublime Text. How to do it?

Tags: sublimetext3

I'd like to to do this on Mac OS: in terminal I type "edit package.json", then system opens package.json with Sublime Text.

I know this is possible from this video at 2:00: https://vimeo.com/75702540.

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an [`alias`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_%28command%29). Something like,

```
alias edit=sublime
```

I suggest you also set [VISUAL](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4859/52050) (to set your prefered editor) like

```
export VISUAL=sublime
```

Comment: alias='/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/MacOS/Sublime\ Text'

Comment: The above command works in terminal, but it doesn't work after add it to .zshrc file. Do you know where I can add the above command, so that it runs every time after a terminal is open?

Comment: First, with what shell? Mac OS X doesn't ship with zsh (it uses bash by default).